# UI automation framework cant find elements on win server 2012

Tags: .net, windows, user-interface, automation, verify

I've been using ui automation framework to create automated test (testack white)
When switching from win server 2008 to 2012, i have some issues when trying to run tests. Most elements are not recognized (no automation id) when running the tests and when running UI verify.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I get the automation exception "failed to get AutomationId"
on automation id that worked on server 08